# Tableless Form with Dates

Tags: html, forms, responsive-design, css

I am not an expert in Html & css, but I know how to make nice responsive pages, tableless, tableless forms, etc...

But I got stuck in a form that I have no idea how to handle. Making forms tableless is easy for me, as long we have 1 field per line, now I need 2 fields & labels in the same line.

I want to handle using pure css and I need to them to be aligned. Real life example would be a form of any travel company were they ask for a dateFrom and DateTo.

Another thing, I am using the framework Skeleton (http://www.getskeleton.com/)

```
1stlabel
|1stfield|

2ndlabel1   3rdlabel1
|2ndfield|  3rd|field|

4thlabel
|4thfield|
```

My current markup:

```
<form>

    <div class="field">
        <label>FieldA</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>


    <div class="doubleFields">

        <div class="first">
            <label>DateFrom</label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="second">
            <label>DateTo</label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>

    </div>

</form>​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give those a specific classname, and set `display: inline-block` on them.

---

In your specific case:

```
.doubleFields div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Should do the trick nicely.

Comment: Madara, here is a simple markup. 1st I need to put the label on the top of the field. 2nd, fields DateFrom DateTo must be in the same line and in the same line of the first fields. Would be a 3 column with one control in each one. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/ucWvk/

Comment: @2Fast4YouBR: Edited. Also a nice trick, you can **include** the `<input>` element *inside* of the `<label>` element, to automatically link them, this also eliminates the need for the `<div>` elements (because you can set `display: block;` on them to make them behave the same.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha a better alternative to wrapping is using the `for` attribute which takes an `id` of the input element: `<label for="user-first-name">First Name</label>` for `<input id="user-first-name" type="text" .../>`.

Comment: Madara & Knownasilya , thanks for the help. So simple and easy... just updated the code. cheers!  http://jsfiddle.net/ucWvk/2/

Comment: @Knownasilya: Giving an ID to every input is not optimal on many cases. Wrapping it inside of it also allows you to use an extra styling hook. I prefer this technique when the label and input need to be close anyway.

Comment: I guess it just depends on the project :) Good tip on the extra styling hook.